# CSS border dissapear on hover

Tags: html, css, border

I'm having trouble with my StyleSheet and I have no idea what to do next.

I created

```
<p class="button">MORE</p>
```

since I wanted text that looks like button.

This is CSS part that I'm using to modify it.

```
.content .bothead a.part .dole p.button{font-size: 16px;border: 2px solid #6d6d6d;padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px; margin-bottom: 10px; border-radius: 25px; -webkit-border-radius: 25px; -moz-border-radius: 25px;}
```

Problems begin when I want this button to dissapear after putting mouse over whole `<a>` that button is in.

I'm using this bit of code to make whole text disappear but border stay anyways.

```
.content .bothead a.part:hover {color: transparent; border: transparent;}
```

I managed to get rid of border using this bit of code to make it disappear.

```
.content .bothead a.part .dole p.button:hover {color: transparent; border: transparent !important;}
```

Problem is that with this code I have to hover mouse over that button and I would like to set transparent color when I hover mouse over whole `<a>`.

```css
.content .bothead a.part:hover {
  color: transparent;
  border: transparent;
}
```

```html
      <a class="part treti" title="" href="">
        <p class="nadpis">Title</p>
        <div class="dole">
          <p>child1</p>
          <p>child2</p>
          <p class="button">MORE</p>
        </div>
      </a>
```

Idea is, while hovering over `<a class="part treti" title="" href="">` these all should disappear. With my code I set all transparent, just border on button stay.

Comment: What do you want can you tell me clearly & shortly?

Comment: can you include a working example/fiddle?

Comment: You want the border to show on regular, and disappear when hovering? You have to hover in order to..what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Hope this helps though i feel it is not semantically a right thing to have a div and para inside anchor tag..

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
      <style type="text/css">
       .content .bothead a.part .dole p.button {
         font-size: 16px;
         border: 2px solid #6d6d6d;
         padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
         margin-bottom: 10px;
         border-radius: 25px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
        -moz-border-radius: 25px;
     }
     .content .bothead a.part:hover .dole p.button {
         color: transparent; 
         border: transparent;
      }
    .content .bothead a.part:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="bothead">
        <a class="part" href="#">
            <div class="dole">
                <p class="button">Hello</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by hiding the container instead of the content

```css
.button {
  font-size: 16px;border: 2px solid #6d6d6d;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px; 
  margin-bottom: 10px; 
  border-radius: 25px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
}

.content:hover {
  color: transparent; 
  border: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p class="button">MORE</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

If that button is nested inside that div

```
yourDivName:hover button{
    color: transparent; 
    border: transparent !important;
}
```

And please share your HTML, So it would be easy to answer.

Comment: That '!important' he used in his code. Here I just pointed how the selector should be ( `yourDivName:hover button` )

Answer (score 0):

You apply styles for `p.button:hover {...}`
and you set them to the desired div: `.content .bothead a.part .dole:hover p.button {...}`